# convert ruby api to a rest api web app

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sinatra

I have with me a ruby app that basically is an API server- calls can be made to that server's IP address and port- to access this app.

Now, I wish to convert this into a regular ruby web app- which has authentication, and follows REST structure.

What is the easiest /quickest way to do this?

I would also like the core Ruby code (which actually powers the API) to be separate from the REST bindings/authentication model-- so that the core code can be separately updated.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would recommend using Rails and [Rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl). If you care about versioning your API (hint: you will) then the [Version Cake](https://github.com/bwillis/versioncake) gem is an absolute must too. People generally don't like it when a third party API changes out from underneath their feet.

For authentication, I'd recommend using a combination of a user id and a token, passed in as either a header (i.e. `X-YOURAPP-TOKEN = ryan-a003c850e1`), or as parameters to the action. The "authentication" is then done by splitting this token on the `-` and then finding the user record, and then checking if that user's API key matches the remainder of the token. If it does, then the user should be authenticated. Store the user record in an instance variable like `@current_api_user` so that it can be accessed in your controllers.

Your controllers are set up in an hierarchy where you have one `BaseController` which contains this authentication logic (as a `before_filter`) and then the other controllers inherit from that. If you have any other helpers, they would go in this controller too. Obviously I'm assuming you know a bit about Rails at this point.

For authorization, use [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan). It's README and Wiki are great sources of information on how to use it. You'll probably need authorization for your API, even though you didn't say so in your initial post.

Using a similar set up to this is how I built the API for Spree, which you can see here: https://github.com/spree/spree/tree/master/api.

---

Other people would recommend the use of [Sinatra](http://sinatrarb.com) over Rails, and [Active Model Serializers](https://github.com/josevalim/active_model_serializers) over Rabl. Others still will recommend that you go with a [Hypermedia API](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=hypermedia+API) rather than a traditional REST interface. There's even [a book](http://www.designinghypermediaapis.com/) about how you could do that.

Honestly, it's up to you what you decide to use.

Comment: +1 vor version_cake, nice gem!